# Haskell : Dots in function

Tags: haskell, max, ghci, function-composition, pointfree

Can someone please tell me why in this function are used "." ?

```
     longestProductLen :: [(Barcode, Item)] -> Int
     longestProductLen = maximum . map (length . fst . snd)
```

Comment: It's for the same reason "m"'s are used.

Answer (score 6):

```
longestProductLen :: [(Barcode, Item)] -> Int
longestProductLen = maximum . map (length . fst . snd)
```

`.` is function composition, so `maximum. map f` means map `f`, then take the maximum, so for example if `f` is `(+5)`, then we get

```
  ( maximum .map (+5) ) [1,2,3,4] 
= maximum (map (+5) [1,2,3,4])
= maximum [6,7,8,9]
= 9
```

In the code you gave, `.` is also used in `(length . fst . snd)`.

Notice that since `longestProductLen :: [(Barcode, Item)] -> Int`, if we're mapping `f` over that list, `f` has to accept data of type `(Barcode, Item)`.

It takes `snd`, which gives it an item, then `fst`, so it must be that `type Item = (Product,???)`. I don't know what ??? is but it doesn't matter for your function. I'll guess `Double`.

Next we take `length`, so `type Product = [????]`. I suspect it's `[Char]`, i.e. String, but no matter, we can take it's length.

So let's work that through on some sample data:

```
  (length . fst . snd) ("|| ||| | ||| | || |||| | |", ("Gruyere",1.05))
= (length . fst)  (snd ("|| ||| | ||| | || |||| | |", ("Gruyere",1.05)) )
= (length . fst) ("Gruyere",1.05)
= length ( fst ("Gruyere",1.05) )
= length "Gruyere"
= 7
```

Putting it together gives

```
  longestProductLen [("|| ||| | ||| | || |||| | |", ("Gruyere",1.05)),
                     ("| ||| || ||| ||  |||| || |", ("Emmental",0,97)),
                     ("||||| ||| ||| ||  | || |||", ("Gouda",1,21))]
= maximum . map (length . fst . snd) 
                    [("|| ||| | ||| | || |||| | |", ("Gruyere",1.05)),
                     ("| ||| || ||| ||  |||| || |", ("Emmental",0,97)),
                     ("||||| ||| ||| ||  | || |||", ("Gouda",1,21))]
= maximum [7,8,5]
= 8
```

So we've found that the longest product length was 8 (from Emmental).

Answer (score 4):

`.` is function composition. It can be defined as

```
(.) :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> a -> c
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but for easier reading, you can mentally just add a variable on both sides of the equation and replace the `.` by a `$` or parens, so your example would read:

```
longestProductLen xs = maximum $ map (\y -> length $ fst $ snd y) xs
```

For reference: The original version is called "[pointfree style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)" ("points" are not the dots but variables).